# How to add lines between matching strings to 1 array index

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file with data as follows.

```
headline
text1
text2
text3
footnote

headline
text1
text2
text3
footnote
```

I would like to add all contents between each headline and corresponding footnote (inclusive) to an array index.

`sed` seems to work fine in terms of getting the lines I need.

`sed -n '/headline/,/footnote/p' text.txt`

However, adding them to the array like below is not working very well, as each line gets added to its own array index. I am trying to find a way of adding each headline, with the text and 1 footnote that follows, to a single index. Is that possible?

```
declare -a array
array=($(sed -n '/headline/,/footnote/p' text.txt))`
```

PS. I don't HAVE to use `sed`. `AWK` (or other) solutions are welcome too.

Comment: you would probably do better to understand the `RS` and `ORS` variables in awk. `RS`, Record Separator, would allow  you to process each block between the empty lines as `$0`. On the other hand, storing a bunch of multilines in shell array variables will likely be brittle and hard to maintain. Maybe update your Q to show your required output and current output and the awk patrol will help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a while loop like that:

```
array=()
while read -r -d '' chunk; do
    array+=("$chunk")
done < <(awk -vRS='\n\n' -vORS='\0' '{print $0}' text.txt)
```

The basic idea is to use `awk` to read the input paragraph-by-paragraph, and then output the paragraphs separated by a null character. The we read `awk`'s output with `read`, stopping at the null character each time, and we append that to the array.